# <flutter> Is there any way to convert HTML Data to Json and get HTML's text data?

Tags: html, json, flutter, dart

I have data like this.

```dart
{ "key" : "key1", "items" : [ { "date":"2022-04-26" , "html":"<tr>\n<th scope=\"row\">\n<span class=\"ico_age age_12\">AAAAA<\/span><a nocr onclick=\"return goOtherCR(this, \'a=nco_x2v*4.movielist&r=1&i=1800009E_000000000000&u=\' + urlencode(this.href));\" href=\"?where=nexearch&sm=tab_etc&mra=bkEw&pkid=68&os=6003060&qvt=0&query=%EC%8B%A0%EB%B9%84%ED%95%9C%EB%8F%99%EB%AC%BC%EB%93%A4%EA%B3%BC%EB%8D%A4%EB%B8%94%EB%8F%84%EC%96%B4%EC%9D%98%EB%B9%84%EB%B0%80\" title=\"B\">BBBBB<\/a><\/th> <td class=\"time\">\n<div>\n<span class=\"place\">CCCCCC<\/span>\n<span class=\"time_info\">\n<a nocr onclick=\"return goOtherCR(this, \'a=nco_x2v*4.timetable&r=1&i=1800009E_000000000000&u=\' + urlencode(this.href));\" href=\"" data-time=\"2022-04-26 16:00:00.0\" target=\"_blank\">EEEEE<\/a><\/span>\n<\/div>\n<\/td>\n<\/tr>" }]},
```

I get these 'String Data'.

The format looks like json . So i've tried to convert String data to json using 'jsonDecode'.

But it doesn't work.

I want to know the way that convert this data to json and get html's text data.

Is there any way to get these particular data?

If another way that get HTML text data is exist, plz give me some advise.

if my question don't have enough information, give me some advise about this. Then, I'll fill it in right away.

Thank u for reading.

Comment: The data you show already is in JSON format. What is you question, what have you tried?

Comment: oh.. i miss the information about data type. I get String Data. So i've tried to convert String data to json using 'jsonDecode'. But it doesn't work.

Comment: try create your own model, copy your json https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you right, you want to extract the html from the Json.

For that you can create two data classes and decode the json into it.

One class for the list items

```
class InnerData {

    final String date;
    final String html;

    InnerData({required this.date, required this.html});

    factory InnerData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return InnerData(
            date: json['date'],
            html: json['html'],
        );
    }

}
```

One class for the outer json object

```
class ExampleData {

    final String key;
    final List<InnerData> items;

    ExampleData({required this.key, required this.items});

    factory ExampleData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        List<InnerData> items;
        if (json['items'] != null) {
            items = new List<InnerData>();
            json['items'].forEach((v) {
                items.add(new InnerData.fromJson(v));
            });
        }

        return ExampleData(
            key: json['key'],
            items: items,
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can get your html like this:

```
final exampleData = ExampleData.fromJson(json.decode(<put your json string here>));

final theHtml = exampleData.items[0].html;
```

I think the json, you have postet, is not 100% correct. Please check it in an online validator first.

Comment: thank u so much. I solved the problem!!

Comment: You´re welcome. With my Solution? Then please check the answer.

Comment: under the score i click the check button. is this right? Thank u for your answer